# Transaction Log Shipping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Have a production server and a report server.
What I have been reading is that the database on the report server has to be in a state where it can't be used.

Is there a way to have transaction log shipping while still allowing applications to query/create temp tables on the report server to generate reports or is there some other setup that can allow this?

MSSQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "restore … with standby" on the secondary which will recover the database but allow the recovery to be undone. Keep in mind that no logs from log shipping can be applied until you unto the recovery.

If I had these requirements, I'd use something like transactional replication off of the primary to create an always readable secondary.